# Sum of finite harmonic series with powers

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is easy to see that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{N} + \frac{2}{N} + ...+ \frac{N-1}{N} = \frac{1}{N}\left( 1 + 2 + ...+ (N-1)\right) \approx \frac{N}{2}
\end{equation} depending on whether $N$ is odd or even.

Can a similar result be found for
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^k + \left(\frac{2}{N}\right)^k + ...+ \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^k 
\end{equation} for $k$ integer and $k \geq 2$? My guess is that the above is $\approx \frac{N}{k+1}$, but I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^k + \left(\frac{2}{N}\right)^k + ...+ \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^k 
&=\dfrac1{N^k}\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} j^k\\
&=\dfrac1{N^k}\left(\dfrac{N^{k+1}}{k+1}+\dfrac{N^k}{2}+\dfrac{kN^{k-1}}{12}+O(N^{k-3})\right)\\
&=\dfrac{N}{k+1}+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{k}{12N}+O(N^{-3})\\
\end{array}
$

See,
for example,
this for details:

http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Beardon201-213.pdf